# exec() and passthru() php executing

Tags: php, exec, passthru

I try to execute a python script with PHP But I got no results:I tried

```
$tmp = passthru("C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\Python27\\script.py C:\\Python27\\file.pdf",$output);
print($output)
```

The results :"1"

While

```
$tmp = exec("C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\Python27\\script.py C:\\Python27\\file.pdf",$output);
```

returns Array ( )

I'm excepted to return a string,any suggestions?
I verified in my php.ini file

```
  safe_mode = Off
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `exec()` says that the `$output` parameter is an array that will be filled in with each line. If you want to turn this into a single string, use:

```
$output_string = implode("\n", $output);
```

Comment: I got no results in my array,that's my problem

Comment: Exit status 1 that you got from `passthru` suggests that python got an error trying to run the script. If the script doesn't run, you won't get any output.

Comment: But When I use this command on Windows i got results:                 C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\Python27\\script.py C:\\Python27\\file.pdf

Comment: Maybe the webserver doesn't have permission to access `C:\\Python27`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
ob_start();

passthru("C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\Python27\\script.py C:\\Python27\\file.pdf");

$filedata = ob_get_clean();

echo $filedata;
```

Answer (score 0):

python buffers output by default. Set environment variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED to a nonempty string, or run python with -u.